# Need help in conditionally apply-template with sorting in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am trying to fetch the first row which matches the criteria and sorted by desc on wd:Completed_DateTime. There could be multiple rows which matches the criteria. For example wd:Instance_Set_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Customer_Category_ID' and text() = 'CRDRG'] in below XML would return two rows but i want the first value of wd:Instance_Set_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Customer_Category_ID' and text() = 'CRDRG'] sorted by desc on wd:Completed_DateTime.

Sample XML -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Get_Integration_Events_Response
            xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            wd:version="v34.0">
            <wd:Request_Criteria>
                <wd:Integration_System_Reference
                    wd:Descriptor="INTXXXX REV FINRA Connect Customer Invoice PDF Outbound Studio">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0ef644a34de5012532e30ad25003dcf1</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_System_ID">INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:ID>
                </wd:Integration_System_Reference>
                <wd:Integration_Event_Status_Reference wd:Descriptor="Completed">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d8b0bcd8446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID">Completed</wd:ID>
                </wd:Integration_Event_Status_Reference>
                <wd:Integration_Event_Status_Reference wd:Descriptor="Completed with Warnings">
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d8b0c34a446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID">CompletedWithWarnings</wd:ID>
                </wd:Integration_Event_Status_Reference>
            </wd:Request_Criteria>
            <wd:Response_Filter>
                <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
                <wd:Count>50</wd:Count>
            </wd:Response_Filter>
            <wd:Response_Results>
                <wd:Total_Results>2</wd:Total_Results>
                <wd:Total_Pages>1</wd:Total_Pages>
                <wd:Page_Results>2</wd:Page_Results>
                <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
            </wd:Response_Results>
            <wd:Response_Data>
                <wd:Integration_Event>
                    <wd:Integration_Event_Data>                        
                        <wd:Completed_DateTime>2020-03-12T08:13:56.457-07:00</wd:Completed_DateTime>
                        <wd:Percent_Complete>1</wd:Percent_Complete>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="InvoicePrintStartDateTime (Required)">DateTime</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Date>2019-03-12T08:13:15.000-07:00</wd:Date>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="InvoicePrintEndDateTime (Required)">DateTime</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Date>2020-03-12T08:13:42.138-07:00</wd:Date>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="Revenue Stream">Customer Category of Billable Entity</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Instance_Set_Reference
                                wd:Descriptor="(TRXXX)">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">df63f2db7473018e586236fcdc00fa06</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Customer_Category_ID">TRXXX</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Instance_Set_Reference>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                    </wd:Integration_Event_Data>                    
                </wd:Integration_Event>
                <wd:Integration_Event>                   
                    <wd:Integration_Event_Data>                        
                        <wd:Completed_DateTime>2019-11-20T11:27:33.111-08:00</wd:Completed_DateTime>
                        <wd:Percent_Complete>1</wd:Percent_Complete>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="InvoicePrintStartDateTime (Required)">DateTime</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Date>2015-11-20T11:19:57.000-08:00</wd:Date>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="InvoicePrintEndDateTime (Required)">DateTime</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Date>2019-11-20T11:27:22.179-08:00</wd:Date>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="Revenue Stream">Customer Category of Billable Entity</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Instance_Set_Reference
                                wd:Descriptor="(CRXXX)">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">df63f2db7473018e586236fcdc00fa06</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Customer_Category_ID">CRXXX</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Instance_Set_Reference>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                    </wd:Integration_Event_Data>                    
                </wd:Integration_Event>
                <wd:Integration_Event>                    
                    <wd:Integration_Event_Data>                        
                        <wd:Completed_DateTime>2020-02-10T11:27:33.111-08:00</wd:Completed_DateTime>
                        <wd:Percent_Complete>1</wd:Percent_Complete>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="InvoicePrintStartDateTime (Required)">DateTime</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Date>2015-11-20T11:19:57.000-08:00</wd:Date>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="InvoicePrintEndDateTime (Required)">DateTime</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Date>2019-11-20T11:27:22.179-08:00</wd:Date>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                        <wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                            <wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio_Collection/INTXXXX_REV_FINRA_Connect_Customer_Invoice_PDF_Outbound_Studio/StartHere</wd:Launch_Configurable_Name>
                            <wd:Parameter_Name wd:Label="Revenue Stream">Customer Category of Billable Entity</wd:Parameter_Name>
                            <wd:Instance_Set_Reference
                                wd:Descriptor="(CRXXX)">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">df63f2db7473018e586236fcdc00fa06</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Customer_Category_ID">CRXXX</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Instance_Set_Reference>
                        </wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data>
                    </wd:Integration_Event_Data>                    
                </wd:Integration_Event>
            </wd:Response_Data>
        </wd:Get_Integration_Events_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Sample XSLT -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" exclude-result-prefixes="xs env wd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Integration_Events_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Integration_Event/wd:Integration_Event_Data[wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data/wd:Instance_Set_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Customer_Category_ID']/text()= 'CRXXX']">
            <xsl:sort select="wd:Completed_DateTime" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <Revenue_Stream>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data/wd:Instance_Set_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Customer_Category_ID']/text()"/>
                </Revenue_Stream>
                <Completion_date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Completed_DateTime"/>
                </Completion_date>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output -

```
<Root>
   <Revenue_Stream>CRXXX</Revenue_Stream>
    <Completion_date>2020-02-10T11:27:33.111-08:00</Completion_date>
</Root>
```

I would need to select this value from an XML which will have lot of rows. So, I am not sure if the approach i am using is effective perfomance wise. Some guidance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think i got what i wanted using modified XSLT above. But I am still not sure if this can be improved to enhance the perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach (to sort in descending order and take the first item) would be to select the maximum `xs:dateTime` with the `max` function and then to select the (first) item having that maximum date:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
        <xsl:variable
          name="max"
          select="let $elements := /env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Integration_Events_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Integration_Event/wd:Integration_Event_Data[wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data/wd:Instance_Set_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Customer_Category_ID'] = 'CRXXX'],
                  $max-dateTime := max($elements/wd:Completed_DateTime/xs:dateTime(.))
                  return head($elements[xs:dateTime(wd:Completed_DateTime) eq $max-dateTime])"/>
        <Revenue_Stream>
            <xsl:value-of select="$max/wd:Integration_Runtime_Parameter_Data/wd:Instance_Set_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Customer_Category_ID']"/>
        </Revenue_Stream>
        <Completion_date>
            <xsl:value-of select="$max/wd:Completed_DateTime"/>
        </Completion_date>                
    </Root>
</xsl:template>
```

As with any other performance related question, the only way to know is to measure in your environment with your processor and sample data.